# Find the error of the interpolation (either Lagrange or Newton) of the following set of points

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

> Find the polynomial that interpolates a function given by $f(x) =
>  x(\ln(x)-1)$ on the points 2 and 3. Use values for f with 4 correct
> decimal places (?) and give an estimation for the error of the
> interpolation.

I'm not sure what "4 correct decimal places" means here, I'll assume it means simply "with 4 decimal places". Using my calc I got:
$$f(2) = -0.6137 \\
f(3) = 0.2958$$

For the interpolations, I got $0.9095x-2.4327$ for both.

I'm having trouble applying the formulas for the error.

**Lagrange:**

[image]

- What is $\xi (x)$?
- What is $f^{(n+1)}$?

**Newton:**

[image]

- What is $c$?
- What is $f^{(n+1)}$?

How do I apply these formulas in this case?

Comment: @Moo I will reply later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the calculations you did.

$c$ and $\xi(x)$ are some unknown point in the range $[x_0, x_n]$.

$f^{(n+1)}$ is the $(n+1)^{th}$ derivative of the function.

Since $n = 1$ (two points - linear interpolation), for the error, we have $f^{(2)}(x) = f''(x)$

$$E_1 = |f(x) - P_1(x) | \le \max_{[2,3]} \left|\dfrac{f''(\xi)}{2}\right|\max_{[2,3]} \left|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\right|$$

The second derivative $f''(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$.

The error is given by

$$E_1 \le \max_{[2,3]} \left|\dfrac{1}{2x}\right|\max_{[2,3]} \left|(x-2)(x-3)\right|$$

Finding the max over those ranges

$$E_1 \le \left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right) = \dfrac{1}{16}$$

Comment: Two questions: does $xi$ or c have to be an integer? Can it be any random number in that interval? 
And,
Is the formula for the error of the Newton interpolation the same as the formula for the error of the Lagrange interpolation?

Comment: Yes, they are effectively the same error formula. We do not want to use a random number, we do not know what the number is. To make life easier, we use the max abs of each of those expressions - it is typically overkill, but that guarantees you chose a number that is large enough. To find those max, you just use the typical derivative, critical points and end point checks.

Comment: Ok, I understand a bit better now... could you explain how you did this part $|\max_{[2,3]} \left|(x-2)(x-3)\right|$?

Comment: The derivative is |2x - 5|. We now set that equal to zero and find a critical point at $x = 5/2$. We use that to find max |(5/2 - 2)(5/2 - 3)| = 1/4. Clear?

Comment: $x=5/2$ is a *minimum* of $(x-2)(x-3)$ though, not a maximum...

Comment: Don't forget that pesky absolute value! :-) See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+%7C%28x-2%29%28x-3%29%7C+over+%5B2%2C+3%5D

Comment: Riight... gotcha. One last thing, on the second pic, the first formula, how would I apply it here? I did $0.9095*|\max_{[2,3]} \left|(x-2)(x-3)\right|$ which is obviously wrong. How do I do it?

Comment: That divided difference formula would give the same result as $|f(x) - P_1(x)| \le$ the error we show above. It is just using the divided differences as another way to show it.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just having trouble applying it

Comment: Can you follow the example that starts on page 3 http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/sergey/128A/polynomial.pdf?

Comment: Yes. I understand what the divided differences are. I'm just having trouble following the formula in the pic. I'm trying to solve $|E| <0.9095|\max_{[2,3]} \left|(x-2)(x-3)\right|$. This equals $0.9095 * 1/4$. This is wrong. I use 0.9095 as the nth divided difference.

Comment: Oh, now I think I see what you mean - you have to use the formula and the divided differences to write out the interpolating polynomial - not just one result from the table. This should give you the exact $P_1$ you already found - see ex. We have $$E_1(x) = |f(x) - P_1(x)| = | x(\ln(x)-1) - (0.9095x-2.4327)| \le \dfrac{1}{16}$$ This means that if you take any $x$ in the range $[2,3]$, the error between the difference of the actual function and your interpolating polynomial is less than $1/16$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not quite haha. What I mean is that I'm trying to use this formula to get the error: $|E| < f[x_n,...,x_1]*(x-2)(x-3)$ which is the first formula for the error in the second pic I posted. I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: Okay, please see Section 18.1.4 and the example using the first formula from http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/khamdia/wp-content/uploads/6%20th%20edition%20chapter%2018.pdf. We use those formulas in two different ways )[ick your poison), for the first, we need an additional data point and for the second, we need an actual function. The two approaches provide a different result, but recall that this is an error estimate, so that should not surprise us. Another example on page 27 of http://people.bu.edu/andasari/courses/Fall2015/LectureNotes/Lecture5_17Sept2015.pdf.